# Swift2: the righteous way to extract a value from a dictionary

Tags: swift2

Is there a cleaner/more compact way to extract value from a dictionary with a default?

```
                var desc = ""
                if let d = dict["error_description"] as? String {
                    desc = d
                }
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coalescing operator `??` unwraps the optional if it's not `nil` otherwise the empty string will be assigned.

```
let desc = (dict["error_description"] as? String) ?? ""
```